# Parse PHP into HTML style parameter

Tags: php, mysql, string, parsing, styles

I want to make the style parse from the information given in the query.

I have the bgcolor & text color that I want displayed listed in my table, and I have tested the MySQL query and it runs fine, but I've tried to get it to run here but it does not provide me with what I need.

The way I tried was this:

```
<?php
include('SQLFunctions.php');
$q = $_POST["q"];
$link = f_sqlConnect();
$ATColor = 'SELECT M.ATeam, T.bgcolor,T.txtcolor 
FROM matches M LEFT JOIN teams T ON M.ATeam=T.TeamID WHERE MatchID = '.$q;

if($result = mysqli_query($link,$ATColor)) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<th colspan='2' style='background-color:{$row[1]};color:{$row[2]}'><p>$ATeam</th>"; }
} else {
echo "<th colspan='2'><p>$ATeam</p></th>";
}
```

On this I get the false side displayed, It clearly is an issue with the first 2 lines of the if statement, but I can't see the issue.  The $link is a global string and works everywhere else, so it's not that.

Appreciate someone pointing out somethings that's probably easy & obvious.

UPDATE:

After lots of testing it's certainly to do with the if statement, but I cannot see the issue.

1. If I run a var_dump($result) I get nothing, showing why it's going
   to the false side.
2. I have checked the two strings, $link is used to connect the entire
   page, so is definitely working, $ATColor can be correctly parsed on
   the false side, and correctly gives the MySQL query, which works
   perfectly if entered into CLI.
3. Just to ensure my query had nothing wrong, I changed it to a simple
   SELECT * FROM matches; it still goes to the false side.

So I have no idea why, there are no errors on the page (I have error reporting on) and the code loos fine.

These two lines are somehow the issue, please help, it's driving me crazy:

```
if($result = mysqli_query($link,$ATColor)) {  
              while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
```

Comment: `$link` must be global variable?

Comment: I believe it is there, it's with $q that works, it's right underneath it.

Comment: What is **$q**? And where are **M** and **T**?

Comment: $q is pulling the ID to use and works as I see it fine on an echo.
M & T are just denominators in the query and are defined in it at the tables teams T and matches M.  They also are not the issue as I know the query works.

The issue is somewhere within: 
if($result = mysqli_query($link,$ATColor)) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

Comment: Any help here?  Appreciate all thoughts.